# xcode does not stop at breakpoint if there is no code change

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I am currently running the xcode 4.3.1, i found that if I don't do any code change and rerun a program with the same set of breakpoint set before, xcode won't stop at the breakpoints anymore.  My fix at the moment is to put in some junk NSLog statement which is very time consuming. Did anyone has the problem before?  Am I missing some setting in preference?

Comment: I can't reproduce that, my Xcode is 4.3.1 too. It always stops at the break points I set.

Comment: Maybe you could try reinstalling Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked to make sure the "breakpoints" button is still pressed.
Otherwise you can try restarting xcode/your machine. Sometimes xcode starts doing weird things if you leave it running.
Last option would be to actually just reinstall xcode.

The problem you are facing seems to be an xcode issue and unrelated to your actual code. I created a small app and put breakpoints but was unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: yeah, breakpoint button is on.  I actually also have this problem in xcode 4.2.  I am beginning to think that there is some project setup issue.

Comment: Try checking within your project build settings? Or it might be an issue with your scheme? I would start by double checking with your project settings and then check your scheme settings.